# one column have date time and date, how to convert date time to date, and keep date

Tags: r

I want to convert the Infection_time(date time) to Infection_date (date), my code is as followings:

```
    Infection_HAI1$Infected_date<-format(as.POSIXct(strptime(Infection_HAI1$INFECTED_TIME,
"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="")) ,
format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I expect the `2015-01-28` keep same, however, the actual output is NA

```
INFECTED_TIME         Infected_date
2014-12-22 23:59:59   2014-12-22 
2015-01-28            2015-01-28
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, mark your code by selecting and pressing Control-k to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `as.Date` function should work, as in

```
> as.Date('2014-12-22 23:59:59')
[1] "2014-12-22"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, very useful suggestion.